# Array_splice index problem in ACF Flexible Content

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, array

I want to insert a row layout from an ACF Flexible Content field in one page (templates page) into the Flexible Content that is assigned to another page (Original). The Flexible Content field group is the same. I am using the following code and it works ok for the whole array:

```
<?php
$original = array(
    array( "sub_field_1" => "Foo1", "sub_field_2" => "Bar1", "acf_fc_layout" => "layout_1_name" ) );
    
$template = array(
    array( "sub_field_1" => "Foo1", "sub_field_2" => "Bar1", "acf_fc_layout" => "section_1_name" ),
    array( "sub_field_x" => "Foo2", "sub_field_y" => "Bar2", "acf_fc_layout" => "section_2_name" ) );

$inserted = $template;
array_splice($original, 0, 0, $inserted);

print_r($original);
?>
```

And this is the array output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sub_field_1] => Foo1
            [sub_field_2] => Bar1
            [acf_fc_layout] => section_1_name
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sub_field_x] => Foo2
            [sub_field_y] => Bar2
            [acf_fc_layout] => section_2_name
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sub_field_1] => Foo1
            [sub_field_2] => Bar1
            [acf_fc_layout] => layout_1_name
        )

)
```

The PROBLEM is: when I want to insert just a specific array item it does not work. Example:

```
$inserted = $template[0];

Array
(
    [0] => Foo1
    [1] => Bar1
    [2] => section_1_name
    [3] => Array
        (
            [sub_field_1] => Foo1
            [sub_field_2] => Bar1
            [acf_fc_layout] => layout_1_name
        )

)
```

Any help please?
Thank you

Comment: is this a WordPress question, or a general PHP question? Other than mentions of ACF in the key names I don't see any WordPress function calls or code here, it looks like this should have been asked on stackoverflow